# Bootstrap stacking columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-grid

I have a silly bootstrap problem.

[image: Problem visualized]

code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:pink;"> lorem... </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:yellow;"> lorem... </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:pink;"> lorem... </div>
</div>
```

I would like to fit last pink div into space above it.
Whats the easiest way to reach my goal?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm4">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:pink;"> lorem... </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:pink;"> lorem... </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:yellow;"> lorem... </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set 2 columns like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:pink;"> lorem... </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:pink;"> lorem... </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-8">
       <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:yellow;"> lorem... </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So you have 2 columns now:

- one of 4 cols and another of 8 cols
- every child has 12 cols to take the maximal width of the parent (4 or 8 cols)

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:pink;">
    <div class="row">lorem... top</div>
    <div class="row">lorem... bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:yellow;"> lorem... Yellow</div>

</div>
```

hope it helps